# Value of a field by default Django Admin

Tags: django, admin, default

I have the following model

```
class Trivias(models.Model):
GIFT_CHOICES = (
    ('gas', 'Gasolina'),
    ('money', 'Dinero'),
    ('xp','Experiencia'),
)
NUMQ_CHOICES = (
    (1, '1'),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '3'),
    (4, '4'),
)
idtrivias = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
url  = models.CharField(max_length=450)
numQ = models.IntegerField(max_length=4,choices=NUMQ_CHOICES)
idtipospropiedades = models.ForeignKey(Tipospropiedades, db_column='idtipospropiedades')
idtitulos = models.ForeignKey(Titulos, db_column='idtitulos')
correct = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
gift = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=GIFT_CHOICES)
value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
class Meta:
    db_table = u'trivias'
```

I want the url field has a default value in the Django Admin, How I can do?

regards

Comment: It's good practice to write your code in English.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you're storing the URL as a CharField rather than a [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)? URLField is a URL-specific subclass of CharField. Also, to set default values, use [default="x"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default), e.g.

```
url = models.URLField(default='http://www.foo.com')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, do not think it was so easy, I will switch to the URL field to thank you very much